# GWT plugin error

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

I'm trying to install GWT plugin i eclipse.
It showing error like,

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42

But there is no plugin installed. And also it is not at all working

Comment: Please install it through the below link https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you are downloading and installling the right plugin. 
You can get the details from below link :
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

Answer (score 1):

You have to run your eclipse as administrator, I have same problem with it.
Also make uncheck **Proxy entries** from  **Window->Preferences->Network Connections**

[image]